# Problems in calculating svymean for factor variables in R

Tags: r, survey, weighted

I'm trying to calculate simple weighted means for my masters thesis using the survey package in RStudio. Most of my variables are factor variables. When I try to calculate the svymean I always get "NA" as results.

I did the following step for all of my variables:

```
data_subset$fTox <- factor(data_subset$PosNeg)
data_subset$fTox <- plyr::mapvalues(data_subset$fTox,from =c("1","2"), to = c("Negativ", "Positiv"))
```

Then created the survey design:

```
QSLab <- svydesign(ids = ~ppoint, data = data_subset1, weights = ~wQSLAB)
```

When I use this code:

```
svymean(design=QSLab, x=~fTox)
confint(svymean(design = QSLab, x = ~fTox))
```

I always get this as a result, no matter which variable I use:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzMWt.png)

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: can you give an example with your data? use `dput`

Comment: do you want `svymean( ~ variable , design , na.rm = TRUE )` ?